# DNS doesn't resolve in the local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I have a Asus RT-AC68U router which is setup to use it's internal DDNS tool to sync my ip with NO-IP.com.

Everything works great **outside** of the network. When I'm at work I can type in mydomain.com and it properly resolves. However once I come home and am connected to the RT-AC68U and try to goto the same address, mydomain.com, it doesn't resolve. If I type in the local ip, 192.168.1.4, everything works great. All the appropriate ports are open and tested as I can access everything when not connected to the local AP.

How can I use my domain while connected locally?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is about NAT Loopback functionnality, which may be disabled for security by default or not supported by your router.

You can learn about it at http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers

You could use specific hosts configuration to resolve your domain with your local IP, or use a local DNS Server to do the task. Last solution let you access your domain without any reconfiguration outside of the network.